# PHP $_SERVER and urls?

Tags: php

How can I get my full current url in php but minus all querystrings?

**Example**

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Would echo something like assuming query strings were in place...

```
http://www.example.com/example?tab=foo&dslip=yes
```

How can I get the same as above but cut off all the query strings?

How is this done in php.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP_SELF is what you need I believe.

```
echo('http' . ((empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'off') ? '' : 's') . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Or the **__FILE__** constant, depending on your exact configuration and situation.

Comment: then you would also need to use $_SERVER['HTTPS'], and prepend the correct protocol depending.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$part = explode('?',$url);

echo $part[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is this:

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] variable returns path of your script without the query string like you want.

if you like to see all variables available in php just try this

```
phpinfo();
```

Best regards